# How do I find the max length of a field (e.g. title field)

Tags: entities, database

I would like to retrieve the maximum length of a field programmatically, for instance the `$node->title` field .

I am writing a module that sets title and I don't really want to hard-code '255'. I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: By title do you mean node title?

Comment: If you are talking about `$node->title`, its field in the database schema is set to 255 characters long and is enforced in the node form via `#maxlength` of the same.

Comment: What are you hard coding the length for?

Comment: My question here was how to get the 255 number without hard coding it so that I can truncate the title - $node->title. I call field_info_instances('node') & there is no title, let alone #maxlength. I call node_save and get a PDO exception. I call drupal_form_submit and get errors I can parse. Reactionary and doesn't help. More generally I want a way to retrieve field constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal schema API has a function named [drupal_get_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_module_schema/7) (D7) or [drupal_get_module_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!schema.inc/function/drupal_get_module_schema/8.2.x) (D8) that lets you inspect a schema programatically and retrieve field constraints.

For instance, to get the maxlength of the `title` field in the `{node}` table, you can use the following in D7:

```
$schema = drupal_get_schema('node');
$maxlength = $schema['fields']['title']['length'];
```

You can also inspect the max length of any field used by Drupal simply by looking at the database schema that defines that field.  This will also tell you the names you need to use in the above PHP to get the right value in cases where you're unfamiliar with the schema.

For instance, if you are talking about the `title` field in the `{node}` table, you can see when looking at a scheme in a database inspection tool such *phpMyAdmin* that it is a `varchar` with a maximum length of 255 characters.

[image: Screen-shot from phpMyAdmin.]

Comment: How to do exactly same thing in drupal 8 i.e get length of an entity field ?Since there is no drupal_get_schema.

Comment: @neha Answer updated to reflect that this function has a new name in D8.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, 
$form_id): void {
  if ($form['#form_id'] == 'node_event_form') {
    // Limit charset for the Event content type and add the description.
    $form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#maxlength'] = 100;
    $form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#description'] = t('The title is limited to 100 characters maximum.');
  }
}
```

Comment: That code will not work, if the new length is higher than the length allowed from the database table.