# Is there a way to get the max size of a varchar textfield?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I have an entity with a textfield created using the core **Fields** feature that looks like this when I inspect the type of the field table in the database `varchar(40)`.

I want to be able to determine max size of the string that can go into this field programmatically.  I.e. I want do know if there is a function I can call with suitable parameters, and it would return 40.

A Drupal API function would be the preferred answer, but a could live with a PHP function if this is not available in the Drupal API.

I was reminded in a comment (now deleted) that I previously had [answered](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/107762/12076) a very similar question.

However, that answer relies on the field in question being part of a schema.

This *new* question is about fields that has been created using the core **Fields** feature.  (I.e. using `drupal_get_schema()` will not fly.

Comment: Did you try using the field definition function(s)?

Comment: @Kevin, no. Hints about exact what function to try will be appreciated. In particualar if it is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single function that will extract the value for you, but [`field_info_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7.x) will get you an array that contains the data:

```
$info = field_info_field('field_foo');
if (isset($info['columns']['value']['length'])) {
  // Do something with $info['columns']['value']['length']
}
```

It it's a core text field, `value` will always be the name of the column you need to check. For other field types it may differ.